# Javascript - Function calls not maintaining order

Tags: javascript

I have following code where I call same function twice with delay of 2 seconds.
But all those log prints inside `isPermanentDisconnect()` are printed at the end of `checkStatePermanent` after `log('After secondflag check')` is printed in the console. Can you please guide me as what is wrong with this code.

```
function customdelay(miliseconds) {
   var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

   while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
      
   }
}

function checkStatePermanent(iceState) {
    videoReceivedBytetCount = 0;
    audioReceivedByteCount = 0;

    log('before First call')
    let firstFlag = isPermanentDisconnect();
    log('after First call')
    log('Disconnect Flag is: ' + firstFlag)

    customdelay(2000);
    log('after 2 secs')
    let secondFlag = isPermanentDisconnect(); //Call this func again after 2 seconds to check whether data is still coming in.
    log('after second call')
    log('Disconnect Flag is: ' + secondFlag)
    if(secondFlag){ //If permanent disconnect then we hangup i.e no audio/video is fllowing
        log('Disconnect Flag = Permanent')
        if (iceState == 'disconnected'){
            hangUpCall(); //Hangup instead of closevideo() because we want to record call end in db
        }
    }
    log('After secondflag check')
...
}


function isPermanentDisconnect(){
    var isPermanentDisconnectFlag = false;
    var videoIsAlive = false;
    var audioIsAlive = false;
    myPeerConnection.getStats(null).then(stats => {
        stats.forEach(report => {
            log('Report Type: '+report.type+ ' Report Kind :'+ report.kind)
            if(report.type === 'inbound-rtp' && (report.kind === 'audio' || report.kind  === 'video')){ //check for inbound data only
                if(report.kind  === 'audio'){
                    //Here we must compare previous data count with current
                    if(report.bytesReceived > audioReceivedByteCount){
                        // If current count is greater than previous then that means data is flowing to other peer. So this disconnected or failed ICE state is temporary
                        audioIsAlive = true;
                    } else {
                        audioIsAlive = false;
                        
                    }
                    log('Previous Audio count: ' +audioReceivedByteCount + ' Now audio count: ' + report.bytesReceived + ' audio is alive: '+ audioIsAlive)
                    audioReceivedByteCount = report.bytesReceived;
                }
                if(report.kind  === 'video'){
                    if(report.bytesReceived > videoReceivedBytetCount){
                        // If current count is greater than previous then that means data is flowing to other peer. So this disconnected or failed ICE state is temporary
                        videoIsAlive = true;
                    } else{
                        videoIsAlive = false;
                    }
                    log('Previous video count: ' +videoReceivedBytetCount + ' Now video count: ' + report.bytesReceived + ' video is alive: ' + videoIsAlive)
                    videoReceivedBytetCount = report.bytesReceived;
                }
                if(audioIsAlive || videoIsAlive){ //either audio or video is being recieved.
                    log('Either video or audio is alive')
                    isPermanentDisconnectFlag = false; //Disconnected is temp
                } else {
                    isPermanentDisconnectFlag = true;
                }
            }
        })
    });

  return isPermanentDisconnectFlag;
}
```

Comment: your customdelay function is async,, you have to use promises  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @MisterJojo I tried this code as well. `const customdelay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));` I got it from SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try making `checkStatePermanent(iceState)` an async function and await your calls to `isPermanentDisconnect()`. This way code execution will be halted untill `isPermanentDisconnect()` completes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it worked. Posting the answer in case it is useful to others.

Changed the delay function to this

`const customdelay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));`

In the below function notice the `async` and `await`

```
async function isPermanentDisconnect (){
    var isPermanentDisconnectFlag = false;
    var videoIsAlive = false;
    var audioIsAlive = false;

    await myPeerConnection.getStats(null).then(stats => {
        stats.forEach(report => {
            if(report.type === 'inbound-rtp' && (report.kind === 'audio' || report.kind  === 'video')){ //check for inbound data only
                if(report.kind  === 'audio'){
                    //Here we must compare previous data count with current
                    if(report.bytesReceived > audioReceivedByteCount){
                        // If current count is greater than previous then that means data is flowing to other peer. So this disconnected or failed ICE state is temporary
                        audioIsAlive = true;
                    } else {
                        audioIsAlive = false;
                        
                    }
                    log('Previous Audio count: ' +audioReceivedByteCount + ' Now audio count: ' + report.bytesReceived + ' audio is alive: '+ audioIsAlive)
                    audioReceivedByteCount = report.bytesReceived;
                }
                if(report.kind  === 'video'){
                    if(report.bytesReceived > videoReceivedBytetCount){
                        // If current count is greater than previous then that means data is flowing to other peer. So this disconnected or failed ICE state is temporary
                        videoIsAlive = true;
                    } else{
                        videoIsAlive = false;
                    }
                    log('Previous video count: ' +videoReceivedBytetCount + ' Now video count: ' + report.bytesReceived + ' video is alive: ' + videoIsAlive)
                    videoReceivedBytetCount = report.bytesReceived;
                }
                if(audioIsAlive || videoIsAlive){ //either audio or video is being recieved.
                    log('Either video or audio is alive')
                    isPermanentDisconnectFlag = false; //Disconnected is temp
                } else {
                    isPermanentDisconnectFlag = true;
                }

            }
        })
    });

  return isPermanentDisconnectFlag;
}
```

I think the issue i was facing was due to `myPeerConnection.getStats(null).then(stats => { stats.forEach(report => {..`

It had to have `await` as shown in the function above.

Then call the above functions.Notice the `async` and `await`.

```
async function checkStatePermanent (iceState) {
videoReceivedBytetCount = 0;
audioReceivedByteCount = 0;

log('after First call')
let firstFlag = await isPermanentDisconnect();
log('Disconnect Flag is: ' + firstFlag)
log('after First call')

await customdelay(2000);
log('after 2 secs')
let secondFlag = await isPermanentDisconnect(); //Call this func again after 2 seconds to check whether data is still coming in.
log('after second call')
if(secondFlag){ //If permanent disconnect then we hangup i.e no audio/video is fllowing
    log('Disconnect Flag = Permanent')
    if (iceState == 'disconnected'){
        hangUpCall(); 
    }
}
..
}
```

Log prints as expected and order seems to be maintained now.

Thank you all.